# Batch parse each parameter

Tags: parameters, batch-file, foreach

I am trying to create a batch script which would perform the same action for each parameter given. For example, giving X files as parameters:
`script.bat "file1.txt" "file2.txt" "file3.txt" "file4.txt" ... "fileX.txt"`
will rename them to:
`"file1.bin" "file2.bin" "file3.bin" "file4.bin" ... "fileX.bin"`
Rename is just an example, I will need it for more complex operations too.
I guess it should be something like `for each` but I'm new in batch scripts.

I just wonder if I could just increment `%1` index...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `SHIFT` to shift the parameters left. In other words calling shift will put the second parameter to %1, the third to %2 etc.

So you need something like:

```
@ECHO OFF
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
   ECHO %1
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```

This will just print the arguments in order, but you can do whatever you want inside the loop.

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this and just add the complexity you want:

```
for %%x in (%*) do (
  echo %%x
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up with was the following.  I tend to over do things, thought I would share...

At the top of my batch file I have the following code...

**Usage:**

```
::--------------------------------------------------------
:: Handle parameters
::--------------------------------------------------------
CALL:ChkSwitch bOverwrite "/OVERWRITE" %*
CALL:ChkSwitch bMerge "/MERGED" %*
```

Then at the bottom (where I usually place all my functions)...

**Function:**

```
::--------------------------------------------------------
:: ChkSwitch Function
::--------------------------------------------------------

:ChkSwitch <bRet> <sSwitch> <sParams> (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET "switched=0"

    :ChkSwitchLoop
    IF "%~3"=="" GOTO ChkSwitchDone

    IF %~3==%~2 (
        SET "switched=1"
        GOTO ChkSwitchDone
    )

    SHIFT /3
    GOTO ChkSwitchLoop

    :ChkSwitchDone
)
( 
    ENDLOCAL
    SET "%~1=%switched%"
    EXIT /B
)
```

To use this its simple.  You just call the function passing in a variable you wish to change OR create than next pass the switch you are looking for and last pass all the params from the script.