# How to set variable in one bat file and send to another?

Tags: batch-file, variables, send

I have two bat files, program 1 is working so when the user enters a "file name" it will open the file and edit it.
However, I would also like to make it so if program 2 opened and the username just enters a file name it will send that variable over to program 1 which then uses the variable to edit the file instead of asking for a user to input the file name.

I tried creating a variable on program 2 and then using %1 but don't know how to go forward from here.

Program 1:

```
set /p FileName=
If exist %cd%\%FileName% start %FileName%
```

Program 2:

```
@echo off
set /p FileName=[FileName]: 
call editor.bat %FileName%
```

I would like program 1 to check if program 2 has sent a variable if not to continue as normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a variable, you would need to use it as an argument:

bat1.bat

```
@echo off
set /p filename="Enter Filename: "
bat2 %filename%
```

bat2.bat

```
@echo off
echo %1
```

Both files need to be in the same directory otherwise you must use absolute path when calling bat2.bat

`%1` is the first argument, you can use multiple argument i.e. `%2`, `%3`

Further reading:
http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=1767

Example scripts:
https://www.instructables.com/id/5-Cool-Batch-Files/

**EDIT**

This if from: [Batch parse each parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457355/batch-parse-each-parameter)

The `SHIFT` command shifts the arguments to the left until there aren't anymore. So after %1 is called, %2 becomes %1, etc

```
@ECHO OFF
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
   ECHO %1
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```

Comment: So program 2 essentially is just asking for a file name and then passing it to program 1. Essentially skipping the process in program 1 where the user has to enter a filename. it might sound useless but for the project at school ive been given it's not

Comment: So it is one program already but its been requested that there's an interactive mode which is program 1 and a "Command Line mode" which is program 2. So it skips the whole "Please enter a file name..."

Comment: It worked! Thankyou, is there anyway to check if more than 1 variable was entered for example: The user enters FileName1 Filename2 causing %1 and %2 to exist. A maximum of %1 should only be allowed. If this makes sense.

Comment: As long as you don't use `setlocal`, the variable should be visible to both scripts if script1 opens script2.